# Calling methods between view controllers using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, viewcontroller, ios5

I've already read the post Passing data to views using Storyboards, but still have problem with calling methods:

Now I have `AViewController` and `BViewController`, both connected with Storyboard (no XIBs).

In BViewController :

```
-(void)doSth:(int)num;
```

So how can I call the `doSth:` method in `AViewController`?

The old way like `[bViewController doSth:123];` don't work because I can't get the instance of `BViewController` in the Storyboard.

Thanks.

Peak

Comment: I have a possible answer but I was under the impression that the iOS 5 SDK was under NDA (outside of the official Apple developer forums).  Can someone confirm/deny this?

Comment: Yes -- iOS 5 is under NDA and cannot be discussed here.  Ask this in the Apple dev forums.

Comment: I found a good post that explains in details how to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920229/xcode-storybaord-transfer-of-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found if i use:

```
MapViewController *mapView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapView"];
```

("MapView" is the identifier i set for that scene/view in storyboard)

and i just tested the old way and it works for me:

```
mapViewController *mapView = [[mapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

i can call methods in MapViewController directly, aka

```
[mapView testMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in your view controller. The first paramter is a `UIStoryboardSegue` object which has references to both the source and destination view controller. This should allow you to do your `[bViewController doSth:123];` pretty much as before.