# What are some good developer resources to make the move to iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, resources, ios5

With Lion and the new Xcode and ARC and Storyboard and the little glitches that many of us have found in trying to make the move into iOS 5, it can be quite intimidating for a junior developer to make the jump.

I know there are similar questions that touch on specific tasks related to making the switch, but not quite what I and probably others are looking for.

So, what are some good resources to help iOS 4 and Xcode 3 developers make the switch to the new technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had quite some success switching using the [Apple WWDC 2011 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) concerning new technologies, especially ARC. If you want to spend a few dollars, I also would recommend [iOS 5 by tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store) by Ray Wenderlich. if you are already somewhat familiar with the iOS 4 technologies. The book currently is not done but digital buyers get the current beta version which is almost complete. You can see the introductory chapters on [the site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) as well , category iOS 5,  and depending on your needs this may already enough to get a jump start in the new technologies.

Comment: Thanks.  I've looked at Ray's cocos2D tutorials, but I didn't realize he had iOS 5 tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Watch some of the WWDC videos (which you can get by going to http://developer.apple.com/wwdc and clicking on the "WWDC Videos" at the bottom of the screen).  As far as I know, these are free for registered developers.

The "Intro" talks are probably the most illuminating, for developers just getting started in the process of figuring out what to do with iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

Here are useful links to help implementing storyboard :

http://codingandcoffee.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/iphone-tutorial-one-introduction-to-storyboarding/

http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219

[Calling methods between view controllers using Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320587/calling-methods-between-view-controllers-using-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I have several iOS5 tutorials on my [site](http://www.scott-sherwood.com) and I have had extremely positive reactions to my [Storyboard tutorial](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219), it is slightly more in-depth that this previously mentioned. I also have a [practical example](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=558) with a Lamp backend that shows you how to communicate with an iOS device.

Would love to hear your thoughts on them.